# How to train a VQ Gan Based on Pretrained Language and Image Encoder?

Tags: gan, generative-models, image-generation

I have trained the dual encoder model (separate language and vision encoders) using the ideas [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/nl_image_search/).

However, this looks like an image look up model rather than an image generation model. What would the code look like to use those pretrained model with a VQGAN (preferably with tensorflow)? Any tutorial will be sincerely appreciated.